# Relation between matrix element of a process with its crossed processes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, symmetry, scattering, interactions

Consider a process in particle physics denoted by, $$(1) \quad a+b\to c+d$$ which is related to the reverse process $$(2)\quad c+d\to a+b.$$ By virtue of the hermiticity of the interaction Hamiltonian, the matrix elements of the process $(1)$ and $(2)$ are related as
$$(3)\quad \langle f|H_{\rm int}|i\rangle=\langle i|H_{\rm int}|f\rangle^*.$$
I am curious whether there is anything that relates the matrix element of $(1)$ with those of "crossed" processes, such as:
\begin{eqnarray}
a+\bar{c} &\to& \bar{b}+d,\\
a+\bar{d} &\to& c+\bar{b},\\
a &\to& \bar{b}+c+d.
\end{eqnarray}
Thanks!

Comment: I think one needs to determine the specifics of the theory at hand first, no?

Comment: you're most definitely already familiar with the concept of [crossing symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_(physics)), no?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform To some extent, yes. By crossing symmetry, I understand that if $a+b\to c+d$ is allowed, then "crossed" processes will also be allowed, if not kinematically forbidden. But do not sure if we can write relations between the matrix elements of crossed reactions. For time reversal, I know, we can use the hermiticity of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Wikipedia link says something about the relation between matrix elements. Do you have a proof of it?